# Why did the command prompt open after I opened the Flash Player setup?

Tags: security

I opened the setup and alongside the setup window, the command prompt opened. What does this mean? The command prompt window is titled c:\docume~1\owner\locals~1\temp\nsyf.tmp\ump.exe

Comment: did you get this flash player from the adobe website? Of not maybe shady... UMP.EXE comes up with sparkmediaplayer & babylon... malware shifty stuff... google it

Answer (score 1):

The Console window can open for various reasons, it may be the case, for instance, that the application you are running is actually a Console Application by definition, regardless of the fact it create its own graphical Window or not, and because of that the system creates a console window for it to display its output.

It is the case with some applications written in Java and Python.

It looks odd though that the Flash Player setup would open this. Are you sure you obtained it from a trustable source? In this case the Adobe website?

Comment: It may have been from Cnet.com, but until now I've had no trouble with them.

Comment: That is one big clue, would you add that to the question, because it could be very important. I used to trust cnet for downloads complety but not since they (or someone else) started re-packaging them, with additional items. For the sake of defamation suit issues lets just say it was viruses (by any other name) and malware and evil programs :-)

Comment: You should always go directly to the manufacturer/developer whenever possible, downloading from 3rd party is always risky.

Answer (score 1):

Command prompt console can open whenever a dos cmd is executed. Running an application from another application can cause it to open. IE, you started the flash setup exe and it ran another application that it probably unarchived from the setup exe.

Comment: So is that good or bad?

Comment: And what do you mean by "from another application"? How would this happen?

Comment: It can be good or it can be bad. Depends. Once you execute an application and it has the rights to start, it has the permission to execute whatever it wants (another application, and another application and another.... like a virus).